# Trigger Test Class if statements

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have trigger called SynchronizeTrigger and is used to update the Campaignmembers status to Attended, Did Not Show, Accepted and Cancelled according to some conditions.

The Trigger:

```
trigger SynchronizeTrigger on Attendee__c (after update, after insert) {
     Map<String,String> matchedRegistration = new Map<String,String>();
     Map<String,String> matchedCheckin = new Map<String,String>();
     Set<String> matchedEmails = new Set<String>();
     Set<String> matchedSurnames = new Set<String>();


    CampaignMember[] cmList = new CampaignMember[]{};

    Public Authentication__c auth = new Authentication__c();
    auth = [SELECT Authentication_Campaign__c FROM Authentication__c LIMIT 1];



    public Integer attendeesAttended = 0;
    public Integer attendeesDidNotShow = 0;
    public Integer attendeesAccepted= 0;
    public Integer attendeesCancelled = 0;

    for(Attendee__c a : Trigger.new){
        matchedRegistration.put(a.Attendee_Surname__c,a.Attendee_Registration__c);
        matchedCheckin.put(a.Attendee_Email_Address__c,a.Attendee_Checkin__c); 
        matchedEmails.add(a.Attendee_Email_Address__c);
        matchedSurnames.add(a.Attendee_Surname__c);
    }



    for(CampaignMember cm : [SELECT Id,Campaign.Name,LastName,Status,Email
                           FROM CampaignMember
                           WHERE Campaign.Name =: auth.Authentication_Campaign__c AND LastName =: matchedSurnames AND  Email =: matchedEmails]){



            if(matchedRegistration.get(cm.LastName)=='1' && matchedCheckin.get(cm.Email)=='1'){
              cm.Status = 'Attended';
              cmList.add(cm);
              attendeesAttended++;
            } else if(matchedRegistration.get(cm.LastName)=='1' && matchedCheckin.get(cm.Email)=='0'){

            cm.Status = 'Did Not Show';
           cmList.add(cm);
           attendeesDidNotShow ++; 

       } else if(matchedRegistration.get(cm.LastName) =='1' && matchedCheckin.get(cm.Email) == 'null'){

          cm.Status = 'Accepted';
          cmList.add(cm);
          attendeesAccepted ++;

       }else if(matchedRegistration.get(cm.LastName)=='0'){

            cm.Status = 'Cancelled';
           cmList.add(cm);
            attendeesCancelled ++;


       }

    update cmList;
  }
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm, 'Attended: ' + attendeesAttended + ' Delegate(s)' + ', ' + 'Did Not Show: ' + attendeesDidNotShow + ' Delegate(s)'+ ', ' + 'Accepted: ' + attendeesAccepted + ' Delegate(s)' + ', ' + 'Cancelled: ' + attendeesCancelled + ' Delegate(s)'));
}
```

The Test class:

```
@isTest
private class SynchronizeTriggerTest {

    @isTest static void testAttendeeSynced() {
      String matchedEmails  = 'test@test.com';
      String matchedSurnames = 'TestContactL';
      String selectedcampaign = 'Testing Campaign';
      String matchedRegistration;
      String matchedCheckin;
      Integer attendeesSynced = 0;
      Integer attendeesNotSynced = 0;
      Authentication__c auth = new Authentication__c(Authenticated_as__c='testing@testing.com', Authentication_Key__c='00000000000000000000', Authentication_Site__c='Test Campaign');

        // Insert Account and Case for tests
        // These may need additional fields, depending on your organization
        Attendee__c att = new Attendee__c(
           Attendee_U_Id__c = 0,
           Attendee_Title__c = 'Mr',
           Attendee_Surname__c = 'TestContactL',
           Attendee_Forename__c = 'TestContactF',
           Attendee_Event_Registered__c = 'Test Campaign',
           Attendee_Event_Group_Registered__c = 'Test',
           Attendee_Email_Address__c = 'test@test.com',
           Attendee_EA_Event_Id__c = 0  
        );
        insert auth;
        insert att;

        //Creates Contact to be linked to Campaign Member
        Contact testContact = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestContactF', LastName = 'TestContactL', Email = 'test@test.com');
        insert testContact;

        //Creates Contact to be linked to Campaign Member
        Campaign testCampaign = new Campaign(Name = 'Testing Campaign');
        insert testCampaign;

        Campaign cp =  [SELECT Id FROM Campaign LIMIT 1];

        //Creates a new campaign memeber, associaites it with 1 provider sales campaign, and inserts
        CampaignMember newMember = 
        new CampaignMember(ContactId = testContact.id, status='Invited', campaignid = cp.id);
        insert newMember;


        // Test that the Last Survey Sent field on the account was updated on Insert
        CampaignMember newMemberTest = [SELECT Id,Campaign.Name,LastName,Status,Email
                           FROM CampaignMember
                           WHERE Campaign.Name =: selectedcampaign AND LastName =: matchedSurnames AND  Email =: matchedEmails];

        System.assertEquals(newMemberTest.Status, 'Sent');

          matchedRegistration= '1';
          matchedCheckin = '1';
          if(matchedRegistration =='1' && matchedCheckin =='1'){
           newMemberTest.Status = 'Attended';
          System.assertEquals(newMemberTest.Status, 'Attended');
           matchedRegistration= '1';
          matchedCheckin = '0'; 
          } else if(matchedRegistration =='1' && matchedCheckin =='0'){

            newMemberTest.Status = 'Did Not Show';
            System.assertEquals(newMemberTest.Status, 'Did Not Show');
       matchedRegistration= '1';
          matchedCheckin = 'null';
       }else if(matchedRegistration  =='1' && matchedCheckin == 'null'){

           newMemberTest.Status = 'Accepted';
             System.assertEquals(newMemberTest.Status, 'Accepted');

       matchedRegistration= '0';
          }else if(matchedRegistration =='0'){

             newMemberTest.Status = 'Cancelled';
            System.assertEquals(newMemberTest.Status, 'Cancelled');
           }

        update newMemberTest;

    }
}
```

The test class I have created for this trigger is covering only 53% of the code. I have an issue covering the if statements. any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have a single assertion in your code. This is not a unit test. It's a **[smoke test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software))**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are more issues in your code than testing the `if` statements. Your Maps are going to cause you trouble for the following reason, [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) key values are *supposed* to be unique but in your case the possibility of a duplicate surname is possible. You are also using a [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) which will filter any duplicate values, again resulting in loss of data for Surnames.

Your query on **CampaignMember** should be using `IN` before referencing your set.

```
WHERE Campaign.Name = :auth.Authentication_Campaign__c AND LastName IN :matchedSurnames AND Email IN :matchedEmails
```

I will assume you have logic to map True/False to 1/0? If this is the case you will need to be setting each custom field on the `Attendee` object that is being used as a Map value.

**Some points to [test](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) against:**

- Build test data in a setup method to use through each test method
- Run through the execution sequence of your trigger and replicate through the insertion of objects within your test methods
- Use multiple test methods to test each test case separately
- Make use of a bulkification test method.
- Test your results with [System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm).assert() or [System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm).assertEquals.

**Possible Test Case** (May need some modifying for Authentication__c obj):

```
@isTest
static void matchAttendedStatus() {
    CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(
        LastName = 'Test Surname'
        );
    insert cm;

    Attendee__c att = new Attendee__c(
        Attendee_Surname__c = 'Test Surname',
        Attendee_Registration__c = '1', // Not sure how you are transalting this posisble checkbox field?
        Attendee_Email_Address__c = 'Test Email',
        Attendee_Checkin__c = '1'
        );
    insert att;

    List<CampaignMember> members = [select id from CampaignMember where id = :cm.Id AND Status = 'Attended'];
    System.assertEquals(members.size(), 1);
}
```

The key to testing your if statements is to use multiple test methods assigning different values to `Attendee_Registration__c` & `Attendee_Checkin__c`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. i will take them into account and change my coding accordingly.